# Asp.net Odata Web API Cross Origin Put and Pacth Request Browser Preflight Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, odata, preflight

Shortly I ll try to describe my problem.

When I try my api actions with Postman, Fiddler everything works fine. But when it comes to browser Ajax Request 'OPTIONS' seems to my API not handling 'OPTIONS' method.

By the way,  my 'Get' AND 'Post' action works like a charm on browser.

**My attempts :**

1. Enable Cors (OK) tried either web.config or global.asax
2. I tried Application_BeginRequest to handle OPTIONS requests. It returns OK but did not pass to my main Path/Put function.

Notes : My app currently in development environment. So my service and client is on localhost with different ports. I am in doubt that its about deployment issue.

**Technologies** 
  Asp.Net Web Api, Odata for Service Layer and react for client presentation layer.

I would be appreciated to suggestion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just solved the problem.

Solution : **Set** **Auth** and **app.UseCors(corsOptions);** config before **app.useWebApi()** code line. 
Full config located below. Really sad...

***Startup.cs***

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {                  
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        HttpConfiguration configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
        //Config
        Configure(app);
        WebApiConfig.Register(configuration);
        app.UseWebApi(configuration);
    }


private void Configure(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var corsPolicy = new CorsPolicy
        {
            AllowAnyMethod = true,
            AllowAnyHeader = true,
            SupportsCredentials = true
        };

        // Try and load allowed origins from web.config
        // If none are specified we'll allow all origins
        // TODO get this value from web.config
        var origins = "http://localhost:5911";

        if (origins != null)
        {
            foreach (var origin in origins.Split(';'))
            {
                corsPolicy.Origins.Add(origin);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            corsPolicy.AllowAnyOrigin = true;
        }

        var corsOptions = new CorsOptions
        {
            PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
            {
                PolicyResolver = context => Task.FromResult(corsPolicy)
            }
        };
        app.UseCors(corsOptions);
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/getToken"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider() // Custom Provider            
        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    }
```